# How to get time with Milliseconds in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm able to get seconds in Time using AngularJS and its "Interval" option but i was thing about adding milliseconds to the same with 2 digits. Below is the code. can anyone tell me on how to add milliseconds to it.

**AngularJs Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.theTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  $interval(function () {
      $scope.theTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  }, 1000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-2" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h3 style="color: blue;font-family: cursive;"><b>{{theTime}}</b></h3>
</div>
```

**Update - On how i found the solution.**

I just did the following changes. Thanks to **Pranjal**

AngularJS Code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.theTime = new Date();
  $interval(function () {
      $scope.theTime = new Date();
  }, 1);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-2" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h3 style="color: blue;font-family: cursive;font-size: 20;margin-left: 20;"><b>{{theTime | date:'HH:mm:ss:sss a'}}</b></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.CurrentDate = new Date();
    });
</script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">

    <span>{{CurrentDate | date:'HH:mm:ss:sss'}}</span>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: but do you have any idea how to convert it to 12hr Format?

Comment: Instead of "HH" in capital, use "hh" in small letters.                          <span>{{CurrentDate | date:'hh:mm:ss:sss'}}</span>